# meaning of the phrase "point being"?

Tags: meaning, articles, absolute-construction

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/GYAk5jCTQ3s). It is at 3 minute and 55 second. Here is the context:

> Point being, for 250 thousand years all power was muscle power and unless you could ride a cheetah you were not going to go faster than about 20 miles per hour.

What I am really confused by there is the use of the word *being*
instead of the word *is*. But also what I am puzzled by is the use omission of articles before the word *point*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer the easy question first: Yes, it should really be "**The** point being..."  But sometimes when people are speaking informally, they drop "unimportant" words, and it's somewhat idiomatic to just say "Point being" instead of "The point being".

**The point being** is an example of an [absolute construction](http://www.english-for-students.com/absolute-construction.html), using a present participle.  An absolute construction works kind of like an adjective to another phrase, and describes something about it, like the cause or the setting.  In this case, it's sort of like saying "Because this is my point:".

You could use it like

> The light fading, we hurried to set up our tent.

where *the light fading* describes the situation and the reason we hurried. 
Or

> My horse having died, I was on foot.

where *my horse having died* could be rephrased as "Because my horse had died".

Another good page on absolute constructions: https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-phrase-grammar-1689049